# Stack columns of different length into one array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I have two arrays:

```
   array([[Timestamp('2016-04-05 00:00:00'), 5],
         [Timestamp('2016-10-05 00:00:00'),  5],
         [Timestamp('2017-04-05 00:00:00'),  5]], dtype=object)
```

and

```
array([[Timestamp('2016-04-05 00:00:00'),  3],
       [Timestamp('2017-04-05 00:00:00'),  3],
       [Timestamp('2018-04-05 00:00:00'),  3]], dtype=object)
```

I would like to create an array from these that looks like this:

```
array([[Timestamp('2016-04-05 00:00:00'), 5, 3],
       [Timestamp('2016-10-05 00:00:00'), 5, 0],
       [Timestamp('2017-04-05 00:00:00'), 5, 3],
       [Timestamp('2018-04-05 00:00:00'), 0, 3]], dtype=object)
```

The arrays are numpy arrays and the timestamps are from pandas.

Thanks for helping

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your two last arrays have an extra bracket.

Comment: Thanks for removing the extra brackets. Now, where does this "array" come from? The dtype parameter let suspect it's from numpy (maybe this should be made clear too?).

Comment: Yes,  they are numpy arrays.

Comment: You could save people a little time and solve your issue faster if you made it clear that your arrays are numpy arrays and that Timestamp is imported from pandas (I assume).

Comment: Sorry,  I didn't know that was important. I edited the question.